# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Dropdown Menu Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla, menu, navigation

New to Joomla. I am building a Joomla website with Bootstrap 3, loaded it correctly and it wa working good so far. I have a navigation menu where the items are a dropdown and I don't want them to redirect on click but rather just drop down a list of links. I am nearly able to achieve that somewhat with this:

**Menu Item Type:** External Link

**Link:** #

The issue is it doesn't drop down the menu. After I click once any dropdown menu items I hover over display their links and if I hover over the one I clicked on only then will it appear. But it will not just appear on click. Help is greatly appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav" style="html5" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution through jQuery. It turns out it wasn't adding the 'Open' class on the first click. It would take two clicks or one click and hover over another dropdown element. Here's how I solved it:

```
jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.dropdown').toggleClass('open')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following either to your theme's js file, or at the end of the theme's index.php file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.parent').addClass('dropdown');
 jQuery('.parent > a').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
 jQuery('.parent > a').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
 jQuery('.parent > a').attr('href','#');
 jQuery('.parent > a').append('<span class="caret"></span>');
 jQuery('.parent > ul').addClass('dropdown-menu');
});
```

**Update**

> I still have to click and then move my mouse to hover over the
>   dropdown menu items for it to dropdown or click twice

From what you describe, it almost sounds as if you have a double nested dropdown.

You might want to use web inspector to examine the actual HTML code being generated by your Joomla site and comparing it with the Bootstrap documentation. I think the minimum you need is

```
<li class="dropdown"> 
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a> 

    <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</li>
```

If still no joy, try taking this dropdown HTML, create a custom HTML module with it and add it to any module position on your site, this might help identify where the problem is.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, I tried adding it to index then to my JS but it didn't work for me. All it does is add a second arrow to each dropdown menu item. I still have to click and then move my mouse to hover over the dropdown menu items for it to dropdown or click twice.

Comment: Have you tried using web inspector to look for any errors? Or if you could post a URL with the problem it would be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: There's no errors in the web inspector, but I did pay attention to what was being added and I found something interesting: When I click the dropdown link it adds: a nav-hover class to nav navbar-nav menunavbar-nav. So when I hover over the dropdown menus like I said previously only then does it add the open class to the respective menu items. I wish it was live but it's on a local server right now.